# Metrics on X. Show that they are equivalent if and only if...

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Suppose that $d$ and $ρ$ are metrics on a set $X$. Prove the following statement: The metrics $d$ and $ρ$ are equivalent if and only if the class of $d$-open sets of $X$ exactly coincides with the class of $ρ$-open sets of $X$.

We say that two metrics $d$ and $ρ$ on a set $X$ are equivalent if for every $x \in X$ and every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that and such that
$d(x,y) < \delta \Rightarrow ρ(x,y) < \epsilon$ and $ρ(x, y) < \delta \Rightarrow d(x, y) < \epsilon$.

Comment: Do you mean topological equivalence of metrics? if so that's too evident and need no proof. Do you mean strong equivalence of metrics? if so nobody can prove same topologies imply equivalent metrics.

Answer (score 3):

Let $d$ be th Euclidean metric on $\Bbb R$. The metrics $\frac{d}{d+1}$ and $\min\{1,d\}$ on $\Bbb R$ produce the same topology as $d$ but they are not [equivalent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics#Strong_equivalence) to $d$.